# Print more than one line from a text file

Tags: sed

I am using the following code to print the second line from a file:

```
sed '2q;d' file
```

what can I add to this code  so I can print two or more lines at once?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed`, you can print lines 2, 3, 10, etc., using:

```
sed -n '2p;10p;3p;...'
```

Answer (score 1):

To print lines from 2 to 4:

```
sed '2,4!d' file
```

To print line 2, and additionally 2 lines following it:

```
sed '2,+2!d' file
```

Comment: For large file I'd offer to add `q`uit command like `sed '2,4!d;4q' file`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to print a range of lines then you can use this `sed -n 2,4p somefile.txt`. This will print lines 2 to 4 from `somefile.txt`.